# Capturing an "HD" video from Webcam using gstreamer pipeline is failed

Tags: sound, video, webcam, gstreamer, video-conversion

I have a simple pipeline which is supposed to capture a video stream (+audio) from a webcam in JPEG and put it into a .mts container, but at the end when I try to play the file (using ffplay) or convert it to other format (e.g mp4) I get some errors like "EOI is missing" or "found two EOI" or "bad decoder"...

Can you please tell me which part of this pipeline is wrong? How shall I change it to get a smooth video stream inside a .mts container  at the end?

here is the pipeline:

```
 gst-launch-1.0   v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videorate  ! 'image/jpeg,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080' !\
    queue ! mux. \
pulsesrc device="alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_AAF8A63E-02-C930e.analog-stereo" !\
    'audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=1,depth=24' ! \
    audioconvert !  avenc_aac compliance=experimental ! queue ! mux. \
matroskamux name="mux" !\
    filesink location=/home/Webcam.mts
```